# NET-SNMP confirmation on comleted table write

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I used net-snmp library to create snmp subagent. I'm wondering if there is a way to get notified after the table write operation is finished completely. Right now I know only that single field from the table was successfully set, but I would to know if there is a way to get notified after all fields which are being set by single snmp request were set.

The reason for this? I want to perform some action after all columns in single row of the table are set as those values are related and it doesn't make much of a sense to make this action before whole row is set properly. To be more specific, I want to do a crop of video frames according to values in the table and need to know the whole crop "window" before doing so.

Thanks a lot for any answers.